# Ruby on Rails - Error on running rails s command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do minor upgrade in my application. I am upgrading the ruby version from 2.3.1 to 2.3.8

On running command `rails s`, the following error is showing.

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:570:in `retrieve_connection': No connection pool for PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:230:in `table_exists?'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:47:in `<class:Activity>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:22:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:19:in `<module:ORM>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:18:in `<module:PublicActivity>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record.rb:4:in `require_relative'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity.rb:53:in `inherit_orm'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/models/activity.rb:4:in `<module:PublicActivity>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/models/activity.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/user/test/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/activity_extension.rb:10:in `<module:Admin>'
        from /home/user/test/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/activity_extension.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/user/test/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/engine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/test/application/engines/admin/lib/admin.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/user/test/application/engines/admin/lib/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from /home/user/test/application/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I am unable to find the root cause. Please help!

**EDIT -**

These are the steps that I have followed during the upgradation process -

1. Installed the new version of ruby using rvm
2. Changed the ruby version in gemfile and ruby-version file
3. Run bundle update (successfully)
4. Run rails s (causing error)

This is the database.yml file -

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: db_user
  password: db_pass
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: mydb_name

test:
  <<: *default
  database: mydb_name

production:
  <<: *default
  database: mydb_name
  username: db_user
  password: db_pass
```

Comment: Is your database up? Try reinstalling all gems.

Comment: Database is working fine and I have tried reinstalling all the gems.

Comment: *I am trying to do minor upgrade in my application. I am upgrading the ruby version from 2.3.1 to 2.3.8*. So it was working, then when you did this upgrade, it stopped working? Something obviously went wrong or was incomplete with this "upgrade" process. Perhaps you could share more information about the steps you performed to do your upgrade, between the last known working point, and the first known point of failure?

Comment: @luker I have added the steps that I followed during upgradation process.

Comment: Looks like database connection/config issue to me. Does `RAILS_ENV=development rails c` work (when in the console try to create and query some objects to development database)?

Comment: @Felix No, ```RAILS_ENV=development rails c``` is not working. It is showing the exact same error.

Comment: What jumps to my eyes in the exception is that the error boils up from an admin engine. Did you name your connections differently (non-default) in `config/database.yml`?

Comment: No I have not done that. I have added ```database.yml``` file for more clarity.